# Property "domain name" is not receiving hits in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed the Google Analytics tracking in my web application. For the last 6 months everything works as expected. I am having analytics and I can track down the user activity. I have also set up some events on specific button clicks.

It seems that everything is working correctly but I still keep getting this notification in the google analytics page:

> Property "domain name"| is not receiving hits. Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly.

I have checked the tracking code of the google analytics and it matches the one I have in my code snippet.

I have also requested a "check again" and the error is still there. I have checked all the html pages of my webapp and it seems that the ga function is loaded correctly in all the templates. Moreover and most importantly it seems that it works. I even connected via VPN in order to verify that tracks my activity in real time.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Any ideas on this? I am facing the same problem. I haven't changed anything on the google analytics side as well but, somehow, it randomly stopped working and says - No Hits error Property <PROPERTYNAME> is not receiving hits.